# php slim missing data for URL segment : id

Tags: php, slim-3

When form post show an error , I want update user account by id

Error:

> exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Missing data for URL segment: id' in D:\Server\Wamp\www\php-slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Router.php:401
>       Stack trace:

php route code

```
$app->group('/admin/users', function () {
    $this->get('', 'UsersController:index')->setName('admin.user.index');
    $this->get('/edit/{id:[0-9]+}', 'UsersController:getEditUser')->setName('admin.user.edit');
    $this->post('/edit/{id:[0-9]+}', 'UsersController:postEditUser')->setName('admin.user.edit');
})->add(new AdminMiddleware($container));
```

Controller function

```
public function postEditUser($request, $response, $args) {
   $user = User::find($args['id']);
   $this->flash->addMessage('success', 'User [ ' . $user['display_name'] . ' ] was update');
   return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('admin.user.index'));
}
```

Comment: What is the url that you are hitting to save information?

Comment: http://phpslim.test/admin/users/edit/36

Comment: the code looks good, are you sure that the form is posting to the right url?

Comment: Make sure that form post look like `<form action="http://phpslim.test/admin/users/edit/36" method="post">..</form>`.

Comment: i maked <form> method was 'post' and it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route

```
$this->get('/edit/{id:[0-9]+}', 'UsersController:getEditUser')->setName('admin.user.edit');
```

You need to pass `id` data to `pathFor()` method. So instead of

```
return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('admin.user.index'));
```

you should call it like following code

```
return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor(
    'admin.user.index', 
    ['id' => $args['id']]
));
```

or simply

```
return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('admin.user.index', $args));
```

Method `pathFor()` of `Slim\Router` class expects one mandatory parameter and two optional parameters.

```
public function pathFor($name, array $data = [], array $queryParams = [])
```

`$data` parameter is for passing route argument and `$queryParams` is for query string parameter.

So if you call it with following parameters

```
$url = $this->router->pathFor('admin.user.index', 
    ['id' => 123 ],
    [
       'a' => 4,
       'b' => 5
    ]
);
```

`$url` will contains string `[base path]/admin/users/edit/123?a=4&b=5`

Suggestion: you should try to use different name to differentiate route.